# unit test for function in lua using busted

Tags: unit-testing, lua, lua-busted

I have a file contain multi function and I try to write unit-test for specific function using busted framework

code.lua:

```lua
function myfunc1(a,b)
-- do someting
return c1
end

function myfunc2(a2,b2)
-- do someting
return c2
end
```

code_spec.lua:

```lua
describe("function test", function ()
    it("test result is the same in myfunc1", function ()
        local functions = require "code"
        local result = functions.myfunc1(500, 200)
        assert.are.same(300, result)
    end)
end)
```

but I get error like this

```
code_spec.lua:4: attempt to index a boolean value (local 'functions')
```

I need my unit test to evaluate output for specific input in `myfunc1` or `myfunc2` while my code and tests are in separated files.

I test different approaches, but documentation is a little confusing or lack of good example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `code.lua` pollutes the global namespace rather than returning its exports. To fix your problem, you can either adjust your test to work around that problem, or you can fix that problem. To work around the problem, you'd call `myfunc1` from the global namespace, like this:

```
        require "code"
        local result = myfunc1(500, 200)
```

To fix the problem, you'd instead return an export table from `code.lua`, like this:

```
local p = {}

function p.myfunc1(a,b)
-- do someting
return c1
end

function p.myfunc2(a2,b2)
-- do someting
return c2
end

return p
```

Comment: In test part how should I add multiple input for example myfunc1(500, 200) than myfunc1(5, 29) etc… And then result of arrest each of them.?